# paging with knockout and breeze

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application, durandal

I'm trying to implement simple paging but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what I have.

search.html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:leases">
    <li data-bind="text: leaseID"></li>
</ul>

<button class="btn" data-bind="click: next">Next</button>

<div data-bind="dump: $data.leases"></div>
```

search.js

```
var currentPage = ko.observable();
var totalPages = ko.observable();
var totalRecords = ko.observable();
var leases = ko.observableArray();


//#region Internal Methods
activate = function() {
    currentPage(0);
    return datacontext.getLeases(leases, totalPages, totalRecords, currentPage);

},

next = function() {
    currentPage(currentPage() + 1);
    return datacontext.getLeases(leases, totalPages, totalRecords, currentPage);
},

vm = {
    activate: activate,
    leases: leases,
    title: 'Hi there',
    next: next
};

return vm;
```

datacontext.js

```
var getLeases = function (leasesObservable, totalpages, totalrecords, currentPage) {
        var query = entityQuery.from('Leases')
            .skip(currentPage() * 5).take(5)
            .orderByDesc("leaseID")
            .inlineCount(true);

        return manager.executeQuery(query, leasesObservable)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (leasesObservable) {
                leasesObservable(data.results);
                totalpages(Math.ceil(data.inlineCount / 5));
                totalrecords(data.inlineCount);
            }
        }
    };
```

The call in my activate works fine and the first 5 results are displayed.  When I click the next button, the data is returned but I get an error.

Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError: leaseID is not defined;↵Bindings value: text: leaseID"

Any ideas?

Comment: Please `console.log` what you get in your `querySucceeded` method in the `data.results` and update your post with the output!

Comment: I stand corrected.  Data loads on activate, then the first time I click next I get the following errror:

[Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty):


After that clicking on the Next button returns data but by then the binding is already broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that I see up front -

You are passing two parameters into the executeQuery method, the second of which is your success callback - but you are passing it your observable instead.  This shouldn't break your query, but I am curious as to what the purpose is.  You are probably trying to just execute the query and then execute the querySucceeded method when your promise is returned -

```
return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);
```

The Q error you are getting is something I get 90% of the time when a promise is not returned back properly.

I don't see anything that should work the first call and not the second.  I am curious what happens when you hit your URI outside of your Breeze query.

One other thing that I would highly recommend that you do in your scenario, or anytime you are having a binding break like that is to prepend $data. to your observable, in this case the leaseID.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: leases">
    <li data-bind="text: $data.leaseID"></li>
</ul>
```

This isn't going to fix whatever is breaking in your app, but it will take out one of the variables (AKA it won't break your bindings)

One more thing I noticed is your dump data-bind, I did a quick Google search and saw it has something to do with debugging - are you sure you have this custom binding handler set up?

```
<div data-bind="dump: $data.leases"></div>
```

Comment: Removing the second parameter fixed it.  I've been looking at the code so long that I didn't even notice it.  Thank you!  


I do have the dump binding set up, I didn't intend to include it here but copy/pasted too much.